# Primitives/Objects Declaration, default initialization values

Tags: java, initialization, default

When declaring primitives/objects, are them initialized?

Which are the default value?

What is the behavior on *class members* and *local fields*?

What about objects declaration on class members?

---

As answered below, these are the default values:

> ```
> Data Type - Default Value (for fields)
>
> byte  0
> short 0
> int   0
> long  0L
> float 0.0f
> double    0.0d
> char  '\u0000'
> String (or any object)    null
> boolean   false
> ```

Please note that objects are initialized as *null*

Comment: It will be 0 in JavaSE as well

Comment: The first code the int is a class member and second its a local variable, that is the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of `int` is `0` and that is the value it will have in both JavaSE and JavaEE unless it was assigned with another value.

You can't have an uninitialized `int` class member in Java (or any other primitive).

In your example you show the `int` is a class member, in the other example its a local variable, that is the difference.

For `class members` JVM will put the default values, for a `local variables` it makes you assign and initial value before accessing the variable.

You can check the `Default Values` section in [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more information about the class members default values.

Comment: Does JVM calls the default constructor for **objects** class members , as well?

Comment: No, its just for primitives, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (Default Values)

Comment: I must add, that all objects are initialized by default as *null*

Comment: Ah you are right sorry, I mixed up null and uninitialized for a second.

Comment: float[] hello = new float[1] // Why this initialization is required. May I get some help please.